# How do I set up a listener?

Tags: text, input, dialog

I think I need a listener, but can’t set it up.
In the code below, both the time dialog and date dialog work.  The little dialog w/ rollers comes up, I select a date/time, then select  and I have my date.  But I cannot get the text input to work.
  I have tried several iterations of this code from a sample program which had:
        bnBodyEntered = true;
        bodyDialog = new TextInputDialog(this);
        bodyDialog.setText("body");
This code showed the text dialog w/ alphabet roller, but the program ran past it and when I entered a few letters and selected  nothing happened.  That makes since as I did not set up a listener.  So I added (as noted)
    bodyDialog.setOnDismissListener(textSetListener);
using several "setOn----Listener" values and It either still runs past, or I get various compile errors.

This is for my WIMMOne watch, so version 7 and no virtual keyboard.  It needs to be a dialog.

(Note: I deleted gobs of commented code before posting - possibly something more, so if it doesn't make since - sorry. )

Thanks, Clark

```
/******************************
 * Wimm imports
 ******************************/
import com.wimm.framework.app.Dialog;
import com.wimm.framework.app.DatePickerDialog;
import com.wimm.framework.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSelectedListener;
import com.wimm.framework.app.LauncherActivity;
import com.wimm.framework.app.TextInputDialog;
import com.wimm.framework.app.TimePickerDialog;
import com.wimm.framework.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSelectedListener;



@ Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("RemindEA","01S onCrt");
    setContentView(R.layout.reminder_edit_activity);

            . . . 
            . . . 


    mBodyText  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.body);
    mTimeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reminder_time);
    mDateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reminder_date);

    mConfirmButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.confirm);
    Log.d("RemindEA","10S onCrtV df");


    //-------------  TEXT INPUT
    mBodyText.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() 
               {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
         Log.d("RemindEA","21> onClkV:Body");
                     showDialog(BODY_DIALOG_ID);
                 Log.d("RemindEA","22< onClkV:Body:" + strBody);

         mBodyText.setText(bodyDialog.getText());
            return;
         }
               } );

    //--------------------------  TIME INPUT
    mTimeButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()     
           {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
           {
        Log.d("RemindEA","25> onClkV:Time");
        showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
        Log.d("RemindEA","26< onClkV:Time");
           }
               } );


    //--------------------------  DATE INPUT
    mDateButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
       {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
           {
        Log.d("RemindEA","30> onClkV:Time");
        showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        Log.d("RemindEA","31< onClkV:Time");
           }
           }  );

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
     {
  Log.d("RemindEA","70S Dialog:" + id);
  switch (id) 
     {
      // if we want a time dialog--------------
      case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
         Log.d("RemindEA","71S TIME_DIALOG_ID");
     timeDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this);
     timeDialog.setTimeSelectedListener(timeSetListener);
             timeDialog.setTime(mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                                 mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
     Log.d("RemindEA","73S TIME_D:" + timeDialog);
     return timeDialog;

    // if we want a date dialog ---------------
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
       Log.d("RemindEA","75S DATE_DIALOG_ID-26");
       mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
       Log.d("RemindEA","76S DATE_DIALOG_ID-27");
       dateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this);
       dateDialog.setDateSelectedListener(dateSetListener);
       dateDialog.setDate(mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
               mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH   ));
       Log.d("RemindEA","77S DATE_D:" + dateDialog);
       return dateDialog;

    // if we want text input dialog ---------------------
    case BODY_DIALOG_ID:
       Log.d("RemindEA","80S BODY_DIALOG_ID");
       bnBodyEntered = true;
       Log.d("RemindEA","81S TITLE");
       bodyDialog = new TextInputDialog(this);
          //---> ADDED LINE BELOW TO CREATE A LISTENER: GET ERROR <-----
          // ERROR BELOW: setOnDismissListener cannot be resolved to a type
               bodyDialog.setOnDismissListener(textSetListener);
          //------------------------------------------
                //ALSO //.setOnKeyListener(onKeyListener) - others     
           Log.d("RemindEA","82S New");
       bodyDialog.setText("body");
       Log.d("RemindEA","83X:" + bodyDialog);
       return bodyDialog;   
      }
      return null;
    } 

    private OnTimeSelectedListener timeSetListener = new OnTimeSelectedListener() 
       {
        public void onTimeSelected(int arg0, int arg1) 
       {
    Log.d("RemindEA","90S onTimeSelected");
    intHH = arg0;
    intMN = arg1;
    Log.d("RemindEA","91S schedule:" + intHH + ":" +  intMN);
    //updateDisplay();
       }
       };


    private OnDateSelectedListener dateSetListener = new OnDateSelectedListener() 
       {
        public void onDateSelected(int arg0, int arg1) 
           {
    Log.d("RemindEA","92S onTimeSelected");
    intDD = arg0;
    intMM = arg1;
    Log.d("RemindEA","93S schedule:" + intDD + ":" +  intMM);
    //updateDisplay();
       }
         };

 //------------------------------------
 //  -----> ERROR: setOnDismissListener cannot be resolved to a type
    private setOnDismissListener textSetListener = new setOnDismissListener 
 //------------------------------------
       {
        private void textSetListener()  // bodySetListener ()
           {
        Log.d("RemindEA","100S BodyLisner");  //<- does not get here on <done>
        return;
           }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

After many hours of guess and error, this worked.

I don't think the "Return bodyDialog" does anything; I ended up updating the EditText field directly from the listener.  "arg0" has a long name of the dialog - nothing usefull.  But you have it have it to prevent compile errors.

This probably is unique to the WIMMOne where there is no virtual keyboard and you need to use their text input dialog.

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
   {
switch (id)
       . . . .  
       case BODY_DIALOG_ID:
          bodyDialog = new TextInputDialog(this);
          bodyDialog.setOnDismissListener(textSetListener);
          return bodyDialog;


private OnDismissListener textSetListener = new OnDismissListener() 
 {
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface arg0)
   {
     Log.d("RemindEA","101S BodyLisner" + arg0);
     String strxx = bodyDialog.getText();
     mBodyText.setText(strxx);

   }
 };
```